# How to force compilation of referenced library when main application is being compiled in Eclipse?

Tags: android, compilation

I followed this [article](http://blog.donnfelker.com/2010/08/05/howto-android-full-and-lite-versions/) to accomplish having full and lite versions of my Android app. So, in short, I converted my app into Library (MyAppLibrary), then I created 2 new projects: MyApp and MyAppLite and in both apps properties I referenced my MyAppLibrary. Everything works like charm except one thing:

Any changes in MyAppLibrary are not detected when compiling MyApp or MyAppLite. The only way to force compilation of MyAppLibrary is to do Project > Clean > MyAppLibrary. Then after that compilation of MyApp or MyAppLite will include all the changes made in the library.

This is unfortunate and basically renders guide from the above link useless. Is there a way to force compilation of library (in Eclipse) every time when main application is being compiled?

Thanks